SharePoint 2010 Search crawl not working
SharePoint Search is not working in our production environment, it is showing no result, when we start manually start Crawl it is showing error in crawl log
An unrecognized HTTP response was received when attempting to crawl this item. Verify whether the item can be accessed using your browser.

Does the account that is used for crawling have access to the content you are trying to index?

as i have checked the content access account have full read access on web application. do we need to check somewhere else? please let us know.

Are you using SSL/Certificates for https? Have you reviewed the ULS-logs when attempting to run a crawl? Did the crawler work and then suddenly stopped working?

yes ssl certificate added in ISS web application and manage trust central admin. it starts and suddenly stop with error-- An unrecognized HTTP response was received when attempting to crawl this item. Verify whether the item can be accessed using your browser. on each web application.

also getting this error in event viewer don't know it is related to SharePoint search or not--- Exception message was Cannot insert duplicate key row in object 'dbo.UserMemberships' with unique index 'CX_UserMemberships_RecordId_MemberGroupId_SID'.

I would simply try what the error message suggests - access one of the sites that you are receiving error messages on using the content crawler account and see if that works and then review the ULS-logs. They hold most of the information what is happening.
